# Getting Radeon RX 470 to work on a H110M-CS motherboard

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I tried to get a Radeon RX 470 to work on a new machine with a H110M-CS chipset (with a 6th gen i5 CPU), on Windows, without success.

It only works in emulated mode, without hardware acceleration, and the device manager says

> "Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems
>   (code 43)"

At the first look it seems like a classical mismatched driver problem, but I failed to solve it by trying various drivers under various circumstances.

- Before deciding, I tried both the windows 7 and 10 trial versions, it failed on both with the same symptoms. (Whether Windows already needs to be registered for some drivers to work, I haven't heard of it)
- I tried the recent stable driver, the newest experimental driver, and also the oldest driver from when RX 470 was first introduced
- I tried it with driver signature enforcement turned off
- I tired it with completely removing the driver before installing another version
- I tired to let windows automatically find the driver it considers the best
- I tried playing with the PCI express native power management settings, for the case it didn't receive enough power.
- I checked that the extra power cord of the card is plugged in.
- I tried both recent and older versions of the H110 chipset's drivers.

Why don't I suspect physical damage? It works perfectly with Knoppix, and it successfully runs the Unigine benchmarks on maximum settings with a good frame-rate. This is why I don't consider a bad connection on the PCI Express connectors a possibility. Taking the card out, cleaning the connectors of dust, and plugging it back in would have been the next on my list, if it wasn't for it working on Knoppix and for the fact that the case is sealed and I don't want to lose the warranty. (sending it back to repair is not an option, as they might just run a linux-based diagnostics CD on it, find it Ok, and return it to me without doing anything, and I would run out of the return period, which I plan to use to get my money back if it turns out the setup is incompatible with Windows)

*Edit:* I updated UEFI to the latest version, and installed the drivers again. No improvements.

*Edit 2:* The power supply is 450W, which sounds strange, as most people would recommend at least 500W for this GPU, but as a readily-built system, they would surely know what they were doing? Could it be, that Knoppix makes a more efficient use of the hardware, and therefore more power is left for the GPU?

*Edit 3:* I heard from someone having this very same problem, and his solution was to install the .Net framework, because somehow it was not installed at all. However, .Net is installed on my machine, and even after installing the newest one, nothing changed.

***Edit 4:*** I tried with windows 8.1, and although it didn't work, at least i got a more verbose error message:

While with Windows 7 and 10, the Crimson installer claimed it installed successfully, on 8.1 it ended with

> Error 1603 – A General Error Has Occurred During the Installation of
>   the AMD Software Package

while providing a link to [this page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/KB1603.aspx).

Following the instructions on that page didn't solve the problem.

I'm suspecting some UEFI setting which bothers Windows but doesn't bother Linux, but i got through every setting which has anything to do with PCI-express. I've seen a long time ago, that the internal GPU was conflicting with the external GPU, and after disabling the internal GPU, the external GPU worked correctly... however, I cannot disable the internal GPU from UEFI, i can only set which is the primary one. disabling it from the Windows device manager doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Updating UEFI (Asus still refers incorrectly to "BIOS") and chipset drivers should have been done before all the attempts with AMD Graphics drivers: https://www.asus.com/us/supportonly/H110M-CS/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: @MichaelBay : I didn't do it because as it worked on Knoppix, I assumed it has nothing to do with UEFI, and also, this would be the only step with some chance to brick the system... But I did it now, updated "BIOS" from the original March 2017 version to the latest July 2017 version, re-installed the chipset drivers, and to be sure, reinstalled the graphics drivers, still no improvement.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. It seems a compatibility problem that doesn't show up with the open source drivers (Knoppix). Typically it's the other way around, it works as it should in Windows and has issues in Linux but this seems to be the odd exception to the "rule". And I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @MichaelBay : indeed, that was my experience until now, that I had to spend a lot of effort trying to find non-free Linux drivers for various GPUs, because the default open-source ones weren't working properly. What bluffs me is that neither the motherboard nor the graphics card are exceptional rarities.

Comment: You could try installing some drivers from [Asus Support](https://www.asus.com/ae-en/Motherboards/H110M-CS/HelpDesk_Download/), especially BIOS, Chipset and video.

Comment: @harrymc  : have you read the question to the end? I wrote that I updated UEFI and that I installed the motherboard's drivers.

Comment: I wanted to be sure you installed the Asus drivers. If the Windows drivers don't work with your hardware then it's probably defective and should be replaced or reimbursed.

Comment: @harrymc : is it possible that a hardware defect causes Windows drivers not to work, but allows Linux drivers to work? I find it highly unlikely that the setup itself would be incompatible with Windows, as it is sold as a readily-built PC.

Comment: It's possible that the Windows drivers do not use exactly the same functions as the Linux ones, and I already encountered here at least one such case. This card should work under Windows. If you have warranty, use it.